# Rails 3.2 - OR query not working properly - Rewriting query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, postgresql

I was really happy using this query for the search form. However, just found out that is not working properly. 
The failing bit is the `.where` which `like` against `params[:query]`. This `like` happens 4 times  against 4 different fields. However, results shows that this is not happening.

```
 @events_casual  = Event.non_timetable.where("events.finish_date >= ?", @time).where((["CAST(headers.title_es as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"] || ["CAST(headers.title_en as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"] || ["CAST(headers.title_eu as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"] || ["CAST(headers.title_fr as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"])).includes(:header).order("events.start_date ASC")
```

I have been trying to transform this query into:

```
@events_casual  = Event.non_timetable.joins(:header).where(" params[:query] in (?)", [headers.title_es, headers.title_en, headers.title_eu]).order("events.start_date ASC")
```

But, this does not work. `Error: undefined method`title_es' for {}:Hash`

I have tried similar syntax. But to not avail.

Any help rewriting that query much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
@events_casual  = Event
  .non_timetable
  .includes(:header)
  .order("events.start_date ASC")
  .where("events.finish_date >= ?", @time)
  .where("CAST(headers.title_es as varchar(255)) LIKE :query OR CAST(headers.title_en as varchar(255)) LIKE :query OR CAST(headers.title_eu as varchar(255)) LIKE :query OR CAST(headers.title_fr as varchar(255)) LIKE :query", { query: "%#{params[:query]}%"])
```

Comment: it seems to work pretty well. Thanks so much for that. Any idea why my first query was not working as expected?

Comment: i'm pretty sure using `||` in your query will not translate to `OR` when AR converts the code to sql. :)